# echo doesnt work after pg_query

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm currently trying to retrieve information from my database and display this data with a php file but it doesnt work as intended. Here is my code:

```
<?php
  require("dbconnect.php");

  if(!$db){
   echo "Error: Unable to open database";
  } else {
   echo "Opened database successfully";
  }

  $result = pq_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM example');
  if (!$result) {
    echo "Error: Cant access table";
    exit;
  }
  else {
    echo "Everything works fine";
  }

  pg_close($db);
?>
```

Note: dbconnect.php opens the connection to the database with pg_connect() and saves this to $db.

I expected that it displays `Opened database successfully Error: Cant access table` because I havent created a table example yet. But I only get `Opened database successfully`. So I added `echo "Test";` before `pg_close($db);` and expected that it displays `Opened database successfully Test` but no, it only shows `Opened database successfully`.

I then tried to create a new table with php so I added

```
pg_query($db, 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example');
pg_query($db, 'CREATE TABLE example (col char(1))');
```

before `$result = pq_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM example');`. I connected with ssh to the server after this and checked with psql if the table exists and it did, so the connection should work properly. But it still only shows me `Opened database successfully` and I expected `Opened database successfully Everything works fine`. I really dont know why every echo after `$result = pq_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM example');` doesnt work. Can someone explain to me whats wrong?

Comment: It might be useful to show the code in `dbconnect.php` as well

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting turned on? Might provide some clues

Comment: I think it is just a typo, you are using Q instead of G in pg_query

Comment: Do you know where your PHP Error log is? A look at that shoudl have given you a big clue!

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` specially if you are developing on a LIVE server that will have reporting turned off by default

Answer (score 0):

Change pq_query for pg_query.

Note you have a Q instead of a G.